# change UICollectionView layout to UITableView style

Tags: ios, iphone

There is one project using UICollecitonView
[image]

layout style is watrerflow

I hope to change it UITable Style

[image]

Is there an UITableView style layout for UICollectionView?

Your comment welcome

Comment: Why not just use UITableView?

Comment: whole project, each viewcontroller based on UICollectionView

Comment: Well, you can [build your own](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html)... But, as a rule of thumb, if you need a table view, use a `UITableView`.